# JAXB unmarshall validation against DTD

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, dtd

Apologies if the question is already posted elsewhere. I couldn't find the correct answer yet.

I am using javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller to unmarshall a XML document into a Java Object. While unmarshalling I need to validate this XML against a pre-defined DTD to ensure the tags in the XML document are correct. Can someone let me know how to do this?